# Collecting text from links which scrapy "click"?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanna collect text from links which `scrapy` "click" in the website.

Consider the following example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class DnsDbSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'dns_db'
    allowed_domains = ['www.iana.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.iana.org/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow_domains='www.iana.org',
            restrict_css=r'#home-panel-domains > h2'),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow_domains='www.iana.org',
            restrict_css=r'#main_right > p:nth-child(3)'),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow_domains='www.iana.org',
            restrict_css=r'#main_right > ul:nth-child(4) > li'),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('## Parsing URL: %s', response.url)
        i = {}
        return i
```

`scrapy` log:

```
$ scrapy crawl dns_db 2>&1 | grep 'Parsing URL'
2017-01-17 22:14:01 [dns_db] INFO: ## Parsing URL: http://www.iana.org/domains
2017-01-17 22:14:02 [dns_db] INFO: ## Parsing URL: http://www.iana.org/domains/root
2017-01-17 22:14:02 [dns_db] INFO: ## Parsing URL: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db
```

In this case `scrapy` has done the following:

1. Open "*www.iana.org*"
   `path = []`
2. Click "*Domain Names*" url.
   `path = ['Domain Names']`
3. In the "*Domain Names*" page click "*The DNS Root Zone*" url.
   `path = ['Domain Names', 'The DNS Root Zone']`
4. In the "*The DNS Root Zone*" page click "*Root Zone Database*" url.
   `path = ['Domain Names', 'The DNS Root Zone', 'Root Zone Database']`
5. In "*Root Zone Database*" page I would start scrapping data, thus creating items. Final item would also have path attribute:
   `path = ['Domain Names', 'The DNS Root Zone', 'Root Zone Database']`

A human being could navigate in the website just by looking at this path/list.

How can I achieve that?

***EDIT***

Here's a working example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class DnsDbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dns_db"
    allowed_domains = ["www.iana.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.iana.org/']

    def parse(self, response):
        if 'req_path' not in response.meta:
            response.meta['req_path'] = []
        self.logger.warn('## Request path: %s', response.meta['req_path'])
        restrict_css = (
            r'#home-panel-domains > h2',
            r'#main_right > p:nth-child(3)',
            r'#main_right > ul:nth-child(4) > li'
        )
        links = [link for css in restrict_css for link in self.links(response, css)]
        for link in links:
            #self.logger.info('## Link: %s', link)
            request = scrapy.Request(
                url=link.url,
                callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['req_path'] = response.meta['req_path'].copy()
            request.meta['req_path'].append(dict(text=link.text, url=link.url))
            yield request

    def links(self, response, restrict_css=None):
        lex = LinkExtractor(
            allow_domains=self.allowed_domains,
            restrict_css=restrict_css)
        return lex.extract_links(response)
```

Command line output:

```
$ scrapy crawl -L WARN dns_db
2017-02-12 00:13:50 [dns_db] WARNING: ## Request path: []
2017-02-12 00:13:51 [dns_db] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'text': 'Domain Names', 'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains'}]
2017-02-12 00:13:51 [dns_db] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'text': 'Domain Names', 'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains'}, {'text': 'The DNS Root Zone', 'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root'}]
2017-02-12 00:13:52 [dns_db] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'text': 'Domain Names', 'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains'}, {'text': 'The DNS Root Zone', 'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root'}, {'text': 'Root Zone Database', 'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/'}]
```

Comment: Why not just start with the "root zone databse" url? i.e. http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: I will need to scrap some data from the intermediary urls too. Note how for this example only I limited places where to search for the follow up urls with `nth-child(3)`, `nth-child(4)`, otherwise it would have crawled whole site. *iana.org* is just an example website, my real target is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can carry over your url text and keep merging it until you reach the page you want and merge it all:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'iana'
    start_urls = ['http://iana.org']
    link_extractors = [LinkExtract()]

    def parse(self, response):
        path = response.meta.get('path', [])  # retrieve the path we have so far or set default
        links = [l.extract_links(response) for l in self.link_extractors]
        for l in links:
            url = l.url
            current_path = [l.text]
            yield Request(url, self.parse, 
                          meta={'path': path + current_path})
        # now when we reach the last page that we want, 
        # we return an item with all gathered path parts
        last_page = True  # some condition to determine that it's last page, e.g. no links found
        if last_page:
            item = dict()
            item['path'] = ' > '.join(path)
            # e.g. 'Domain Names > The DNS Root Zone > Root Zone Database'
            return item
```

This spider will keep crawling urls saving the url text each time to `meta['path']` when some condition is met it will return an item with all of the path values encountered so far.

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. I need crawler to create this path, thus collect text of the urls it's traversing. Initially this list is empty.

Comment: @NarūnasK and this path is what? A field in an item? You can just carry over current url or name of it simply by adding it to Requests meta parameter and then retrieving it, similarly to my example.

Comment: I just edited question, I hope it makes more sense now. In general yes, the *path* could be a `scrapy.Field()`. I created this question, because I fail to understand the life time of an item. If item is created when crawler is in `Domain Names`, is this item still alive when crawler get to `Root Zone Database`? How can I access this item?

Comment: Could you edit your answer to match my question, as now it's showing the opposite of what I need.

Comment: @NarūnasK The lifetime of an item is as long as it's not returned at parse method and set to the pipeline stage. However you don't really need to do that. I'll edit a new example to illustrate this.